# How to reset SSHD config to vanilla / system default settings on 10.13?

Tags: high-sierra, ssh

I'm having some really strange issues where workstations can no longer perform password-less (key based) `ssh` login to one particular workstation on macOS 10.13 now.  All other workstations can use keys just fine to log into one another, but one is presenting seemingly unfounded problems here.

I've used `-vvv` and `-G` to compare login settings.  I've diffed `sshd` configs between workstations.  I've tried different kinds of keys (dsa, rsa, ed25519). Nothing works and there doesn't seem to be any indication as to WHY.

So in a last ditch effort here, I thought I should probably reset every last possible thing that could effect `sshd` on macOS in hopes that I can start from scratch and see some success...

Thus, how does one reset `sshd` to default system OS settings on 10.13, aside from just copying `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` from a vanilla install?  Anything else that needs to be reset?